# Error de conexion Mysql C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

Al momento de ejecutar un select para conectarme a una base de datos de Mysql me aparece la advertencia de Mysql connection cannot be open el fragmento de codigo que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
private string mensaje;
        private string usuario;
        private string clave;
        private string tipo;

        public string Mensaje
        {
            get { return mensaje; }
            set { mensaje = value; }
        }
        public string Usuario
        {
            get { return usuario; }
            set { usuario = value; }
        }
        public string Clave
        {
            get { return clave; }
            set { clave = value; }
        }

        public string Tipo
        {
            get { return tipo; }
            set { tipo = value; }
        }

        public bool Verificar()
        {
            bool resultado = false;

            var comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO = @cargo and USUARIO = @usuario and PASS = @pass");
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo", tipo);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", clave);

            CONEXION.ObtenerConexion();
            MySqlDataReader ejecuta = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (ejecuta.Read())
            {
                resultado = true;
                mensaje = "Su Logueo Fue Ingresado Correctamente \n \n               Bienvenido al Sistema ";
            }
            else
            {
                mensaje = "         Excedio el Limite de Intentos al Sistema \n \nEspere unos Minutos y Ingrese Su Logueo Otra Vez";
            }
            return resultado;
        }

public static MySqlConnection ObtenerConexion()
        {
            MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; port=xxxx; database=tabernac_vverdadera; Uid=xxx; pwd=xxxxxx;");
            conectar.Open();
            return conectar;
        }
```

Comment: Revisa si tienes conexión a la ip donde está alojado el server MySql

Comment: Más detalles sobre el error, si hay código de informe también. Cuanto más detalles esté en su pregunta, más rápido puede obtener una respuesta. Recientemente tuve un error con conexión, el problema era la versión de MySQL 4.x muy antigua para las bibliotecas actuales de conexión. He tenido que buscar bibliotecas más antiguas.

Comment: Postea el codigo del metodo `CONEXION.ObtenerConexion`

Comment: listo he puesto la cadena de conexion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que asignar el resultado de llamar a `CONEXION.ObtenerConexion()` al MySqlCommand para que pueda utilizarlo.

Después de leer los resultados no olvides cerrar la conexión con `.Close()`

```
public bool Verificar()
{
    bool resultado = false;

    var conexion = CONEXION.ObtenerConexion();
    var comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO = @cargo and USUARIO = @usuario and PASS = @pass", conexion);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo", tipo);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
    comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", clave);

    MySqlDataReader ejecuta = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (ejecuta.Read())
    {
        resultado = true;
        mensaje = "Su Logueo Fue Ingresado Correctamente \n \n               Bienvenido al Sistema ";
    }
    else
    {
        mensaje = "         Excedio el Limite de Intentos al Sistema \n \nEspere unos Minutos y Ingrese Su Logueo Otra Vez";
    }

    conexion.Close();
    return resultado;
}
```

Mejor aún puedes mejorar el código de arriba si utilizas el keyword `using` que permitirá llamar automáticamente al método `.Dispose()` de las clases que implementen `IDisposable` como `MySqlConnection` y `MySqlDataReader`. Esto cerrará también la conexión automáticamente.

```
public bool Verificar()
{
    using (var conexion = CONEXION.ObtenerConexion())
    {
        using (var comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lgn WHERE CARGO = @cargo and USUARIO = @usuario and PASS = @pass", conexion))
        {
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cargo", tipo);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", usuario);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", clave);

            using (var reader = comando.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    mensaje = "Su Logueo Fue Ingresado Correctamente \n \n               Bienvenido al Sistema ";
                   return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    mensaje = "         Excedio el Limite de Intentos al Sistema \n \nEspere unos Minutos y Ingrese Su Logueo Otra Vez";
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```